# iTop reset admin password

Tags: cmdb

Imagine you load an external iTop save to your test server, but then you're locked out because your admin password don't work anymore.
(This story is fiction. Any resemblance to actual event is purely coincidental.)

How to reset admin password on iTop (given server access) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### With access to the database

```
mysql -e 'update itop.priv_user_local set password_hash="$2y$10$vRSLaXl12M7Y70Ucf6KbLuzb.tZbeypqKyZHXWkjgeJCrPYfFwv9a" where id = 1;'
```

will set the password to `admin` (for the account with id=1, should be admin).
Keep that in your shell history, because MySQL history ignores any command with `password` in it.

#### With access to the itop install files

With the iTop toolkit installed.
There is a `reset_admin_account.php` [that you can download here](https://sourceforge.net/p/itop/discussion/general/thread/e320aad0/) and put in `itop/toolkit` folder, the password `admin` is too simple and not accepted, you must edit it to have something more secure, then just go to the page.